# AAD Germany : no shared MS Graph permissions available for app registration?

Tags: graph, permissions, calendar, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When setting up an app under 'App registrations' on

https://portal.microsoftazure.de

and then adding the Microsoft Graph as the API under the Required permissions section in the Settings of the app in don't see any .Shared scopes there, so for example for our calendar app we need to use the scope

https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read.Shared

which is not listed there.

[View of required permissions for MS Graph on Azure Active Directory Germany](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATp03.png)

Do I need to enable something first to get those shared permissions show up in the portal?

Comment: from this resource https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/softwaresimian/2017/10/05/using-postman-to-call-the-graph-api-using-azure-active-directory-aad/ the Calendar.Read.Shared indeed shows up when registering the App in AAD Germany. I also tried with a non free account but still the same list of MS Graph scopes show up. So wondering if the Germany cloud does not provide those scopes?

Comment: indeed just signed up under portal.azure.com for the global cloud and when adding an app the Calendars.Read.Shared scope shows up under the Microsoft Graph API, so seems like there is indeed a restriction in the Germany cloud for that?